# How to insert at caret position of contenteditable using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, contenteditable, caret

I used to have code like this:

```
this.insertNodeAtCaret = function(node) {

            var sel, range, html;

            function containerIsEditable(selection) {
                return $(selection.anchorNode).parent().hasClass("editable");
            }

            if (window.getSelection) {
                sel = window.getSelection();
                // only if it is a caret otherwise it inserts
                // anywhere!
                if (containerIsEditable(sel) && sel.getRangeAt
                        && sel.rangeCount) {
                    var previousPosition = sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
                    sel.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(node);
                }
            } 
            else if (document.selection
                    && document.selection.createRange) {
                range = document.selection.createRange();
                html = (node.nodeType == 3) ? node.data
                        : node.outerHTML;
                range.pasteHTML(html);  

            }

        };
```

but in TypeScript 1.5 Selection was removed from Document (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes), so I don't know how to get it working .. I tried with window.getSelection() but without results

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but in TypeScript 1.5 Selection was removed from Document

That was *specific to internet explorer* and *not available in general for all browsers*. So it was removed. However you can use it *unsafely* (by treating `document` as `any`) quite easily. Here is your code sample refactored to compile without error:

```
const insertNodeAtCaret = function (node) {
    const doc = document as any;

    var sel, range, html;

    function containerIsEditable(selection) {
        return $(selection.anchorNode).parent().hasClass("editable");
    }

    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        // only if it is a caret otherwise it inserts
        // anywhere!
        if (containerIsEditable(sel) && sel.getRangeAt
            && sel.rangeCount) {
            var previousPosition = sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
            sel.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(node);
        }
    }
    else if (doc.selection
        && doc.selection.createRange) {
        range = doc.selection.createRange();
        html = (node.nodeType == 3) ? node.data
            : node.outerHTML;
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
};
```

Of course this assumes that you know what you are doing, more than the compiler knows.

## Update

> how can I see the compatibility of those among browsers and what is available

You can see the compatability chart of window.getSelection here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

`document.selection` was IE only/specific and has been removed : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Some other way that will make it compatible with all browsers?

Comment: Needs runtime support. Means you need to have a runtime function. Options are `polyfill` OR `shim`. What you have is a shim and its good enough.

Comment: how can I see the compatibility of those among browsers and what is available? Thanks